# Check function exists in PowerShell module

Tags: powershell

I’ve the following PowerShell script which searches in a directory for PowerShell module). All found modules will be imported and stored in a list (using the -PassThru) option.
The scrip iterates over the imported modules and invokes a function defined in the module:

```
# Discover and import all modules
$modules = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Management.Automation.PSModuleInfo]
$moduleFiles = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path "$PSScriptRoot\MyModules\" -Filter "Module.psm1"
foreach( $x in $moduleFiles ) {
    $modules.Add( (Import-Module -Name $x.FullName -PassThru) )
}

# All configuration values
$config = @{
    KeyA = "ValueA"
    KeyB = "ValueB"
    KeyC = "ValueC"
}

# Invoke 'FunctionDefinedInModule' of each module
foreach( $module in $modules ) {
    # TODO: Check function 'FunctionDefinedInModule' exists in module '$module '
    & $module FunctionDefinedInModule $config
}
```

Now I would like to first check if a function is defined in a module before it gets invoked.
How can such a check be implemented?

The reason for adding the check if to avoid the exception thrown when calling a function which doesn’t exists:

```
& : The term ‘FunctionDefinedInModule’ is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Get-Command` can tell you this. You can even use module scope to be sure it comes from a specific module

```
get-command activedirectory\get-aduser -erroraction silentlycontinue
```

For example. Evaluate that in an if statement and you should be good to go.

Comment: The number of modules is dynamic and the script doesn’t know the names of the modules. How can I set the “current” module as scope?

Comment: Based on your answer I was able to figure out the correct syntax:  
`foreach( $module in $modules ) { if ( Get-Command ($module.Name + '\NotExisting') -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ) { Write-Host "Exists in module $($module.Name)"  } }`

Answer (score 8):

Use `Get-Command` to check if a function currently exists

```
if (Get-Command 'FunctionDefinedInModule' -errorAction SilentlyContinue) {
    "FunctionDefinedInModule exists"
}
```

Comment: Most of the modules will contain a function with the name ‘FunctionDefinedInModule’. I need a way to check if the function exists in the “current” module.

Answer (score 2):

If many functions need to be checked

```
try{
    get-command -Name Get-MyFunction -ErrorAction Stop
    get-command -Name Get-MyFunction2 -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch{
    Write-host "Load Functions first prior to laod the current script"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Test-Path -Path Function:\<function name>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try adding this function to your module?

```
function DoesFunctionExists {
    param(
        [string]$Function
    )
    
    $FunList = gci function:$Function -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue'
    foreach ($FunItem in $FunList) {
        if ($FunItem.Name -eq $Function) {
            return $true
        }
    }
    return $false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed it so often that I wrote [module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ProductivityTools.PSTestCommandExists/) for this.

[image: Example]